# Jupyter notebook fails for a code that works in command line

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am using a command as described in the readme of the below repo:

https://github.com/aminnayebi/HesBO/tree/master/BLOSSOM

which is:

```
! python blossom_run.py Hartmann6 100 6 6 1 1
```

When executing it in the command line or in jupyter notebook like the above line with "!" it works.

But if I copy the codes from blossom_run.py and give the same arguments to it it fails after a few iteration.

```
import gpbo
from BLOSSOM.embd_functions import *
import numpy as np
import time
import logging
import pickle
import sys

path ='/home/XXX/HesBO/BLOSSOM/blossom_results'

test_func     = 'Hartmann6'
total_itr     = 99
low_dim       = 6
high_dim      = 6
init_n        = 1
rep = job_id  = 1
noise_var = s = 0

bx_size       = 1


act_var      = np.arange(high_dim)
high_to_low  = np.random.choice(range(low_dim), high_dim)
sign         = np.random.choice([-1, 1], high_dim)

f = Hartmann6(act_var, high_to_low, sign=sign, bx_size=bx_size, noise_var=noise_var)

file_name=test_func+'_blossom_d'+str(low_dim)+'_D'+str(high_dim)+'_rep_'+str(rep)+'.csv'
C=gpbo.core.config.eimledefault(f, low_dim, total_itr, s, path, file_name)

if noise_var>0:
    file_name_params = 'blossom_results/param_'+ test_func +'_blossom_d'+str(low_dim)+'_D'+str(high_dim)+'_rep_'+str(rep)
    pickle.dump([high_to_low, sign], open(file_name_params, 'wb'))
```

With the above code written in a Jupyter Notebook it fails after a few iterations and returns this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 out = gpbo.search(C)
>
> ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/HesBO-qpst6LpL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpbo/core/optimize.py
>   in search(optconfig, initdata)
>       305                                      optconfig.ojfchar,optconfig.chooser,optconfig.choosepara,initdata=initdata)
>       306 
>   --> 307     return O.run()
>       308 
>       309
>
> ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/HesBO-qpst6LpL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpbo/core/optimize.py
>   in run(self)
>       113             mode,self.choosepersist,chooseaux = wrap(self.choosefn,self.state,self.choosepersist,**self.choosepara)
>       114             self.aqpara[mode]['choosereturn']=chooseaux
>   --> 115             x,ev,self.aqpersist[mode],aqaux = wrap(self.aqfn[mode],self.state,self.aqpersist[mode],**self.aqpara[mode])
>       116             t1 = time.clock()
>       117             self.state.aux = aqaux
>
> ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/HesBO-qpst6LpL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gpbo/core/optimize.py
>   in wrap(fn, optstate, persist, **para)
>       267         if optstate.condition>-20:
>       268             logger.info('using raised noise floor {} in {}'.format(optstate.condition,fn))
>   --> 269         return fn(optstate,persist,**para)
>       270     except gpbo.core.GPdc.GPdcError as e:
>       271         traceback.print_exc()
>
> gpbo/core/acquisitions.pyx in gpbo.core.acquisitions.EIMAPaq
>   (gpbo/core/acquisitions.c:5018)()
>
> gpbo/core/optutils.pyx in gpbo.core.optutils.twopartopt
>   (gpbo/core/optutils.c:15787)()
>
> gpbo/core/optutils.pyx in gpbo.core.optutils.silentdirectwrapped
>   (gpbo/core/optutils.c:14975)()
>
> gpbo/core/optutils.pyx in gpbo.core.optutils.silentdirect
>   (gpbo/core/optutils.c:13317)()
>
> TypeError: an integer is required (got type OutStream)

I have tried also to putting the same exact code from above in a python file and try the python file in a command line where it works there so I am sure there is no bug in the code and only something strange about running it in Jupyter Notebook instead of the terminal

Is there a solution about it?